# Where maven places library files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have simple maven application in `Eclipse`:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class myApp {


    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(myApp.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        logger.info("hello");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I have defined ed `slf4j` dependencies and project runs fine. I suppose `Maven` somehow downloads libraries after definition in `pom.xml`. But where they are?  Where Maven project places these `slf4j` jars?

Comment: they are in your `$HOME/.m2/repository` directory. The folders structure corresponds to the `groupId` of each dependency you defined in your pom.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The libs will be stored in `${user.home}/.m2/repository/` by default, as you can see in the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html)